# PDO / PHP conditions on number of rows being returned not being met

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have the following code:

```
<?php
$stmt = $db->prepare("select * from products where `price`=:price and `id`=:id and date => NOW()");
$stmt->bindParam(":price", $_GET['price'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(":id", $_GET['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
if ($stmt->execute() == true){
    if($stmt->rowCount()==1){
        echo "1 row";
    }else{
        echo "more than 1 row";
    }
}else{
    echo "nothing returned";
}
?>
```

If there is 1 match in the db I get :1 row outputted
If more than 1 row i still get : 1 row outputted
and if there is no matches I get:

PDOStatement::execute() [pdostatement.execute]: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '=> NOW()' at line 1

Please can someone help with this

Thanks

Ps. the db connection definitely works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you'd only experience this problem under certain conditions, but it appears that your comparison operator has switched characters.

`date => NOW()`

should be

`date >= NOW()`

---

At first glance, I assumed it was because `DATE` is a reserved word that you're using as a column name without backticks. But, [according to the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html):

> MySQL permits some keywords to be used as unquoted identifiers because
>   many people previously used them. Examples are those in the following
>   list:
>
> ACTION
>   BIT
>   DATE
>   ...

Comment: Hi, I just found the same problems as you have listed that has got things working. Sorry for the silly question I guess it just it's 6.00am here and been working all night! Thanks